# Dürfen mehrere Apostrophe kurz hintereinander vorkommen? Wie sind Leerzeichen drumherum zu setzen?

Tags: spelling, apostrophe

Der Apostroph `’` kann Buchstaben ersetzen:

> Ich habe heute ein Geschenk bekomm’.

In diesem Beispiel ersetzt der Apostroph die beiden Buchstaben *en*.

Betrachte das Beispiel:

> Ich hab’n bisschen Heimweh.

Sollte lieber ein Leerzeichen vor dem Apostroph gesetzt werden?

Und kann man auch zweimal das Apostroph verwenden?

Ist

> Ich hab’n’ Führerschein.

Hier soll das erste Apostroph *ei* und das zweite *en* ersetzen.

Comment: Du meinst "Ich hab' 'n Führerschein? Wenn man vorne was ersetzt, kann man den Apostroph nicht hinten setzen u. umgekehrt. "Ich habei en Führerschein" kann es auch nicht sein - also sortier das mal bitte!

Comment: Ah, mir dämmert, das soll "Ich hab' 'n' Führerschein" heißen. Die Leerstelle verschwindet nicht - wieso sollte sie das tun?

Answer (score 5):

Grundsätzlich sollten einzelne Wörter auch als einzelne Wörter verbleiben. Deswegen wäre es zunächst einmal besser, deine erste Verkürzung folgendermaßen zu schreiben:

> Ich hab ’n bisschen Heimweh.

Hierbei fällt auf, dass das fehlende Schluss-*e* von *hab(e)* laut den derzeit gültigen Rechtschreibregeln *keinen* Apostroph verlangt, denn die Form ist nicht schwer zu verstehen. In solchen Fällen, wenn ein sehr kurzes Wort weiter verkürzt wurde und beide fast als Einheit gesprochen werden, ist es auch erlaubt, beides zusammenzuschreiben. Also wäre möglich:

> Ich hab’n bisschen Heimweh.

Bei der Verkürzung von *einen,* die dein zweites Beispiel ausmacht, wird in der Regel davon ausgegangen, dass das *hinterste n* dasjenige ist, das nach der Verkürzung übrig bleibt. Deswegen wäre dein zweites Beispiel meines Erachtens mit nur einem Apostroph zu schreiben:

> Ich hab ’n Führerschein.

Meinen Sprachgebrauch würde allerdings folgende Schreibweise besser wiedergeben:

> Ich hab ’nen Führerschein.

Mehrere Wörter können so natürlich auch mehrfach verkürzt oder zu einem zusammengefasst werden, wie das folgende Beispiel zeigt. Allerdings ist es oft besser lesbar, wenn man sie getrennt lässt:

> Ha’m’S’n g’seh’n?
>
> Ha’m S’ ’n g’seh’n?
>
> Haben Sie ihn gesehen?

Comment: @Kristina Und wie unterscheidet sich jetzt *Ich hab 'n Führerschein* von Jans Beispiel *Ich hab 'n bisschen Heimweh*? Nur dadurch, dass bei *ein bisschen Heimweh* ein Dipthong weggelassen wird und bei *'n Führerschein* das *eine*? Ich glaube, dass das keinen Unterschied ausmacht und Jan nennt das ja auch als gültige Verkürzung.

Comment: @Kristina Ja, wie ich schon schrieb. Ich glaube trotzdem, dass das richtig ist. Ich sage ja auch *Ich hab'n dicken Hals*. Auch da lasse ich das *eine* weg.

Answer (score 1):

Ich denke nicht so wie Jan, dass das hinterste n dasjenige ist, das nach der Verkürzung übrig bleibt. Denn statt

> Ich hab einen Führerschein

sagt man oft einfach

> Ich hab ein' Führerschein

und wenn man das weiter verkürzt ("ei" beim Sprechen weglässt, beim Schreiben also durch ein Apostroph ersetzt), dann erhält man:

> Ich hab 'n' Führerschein

und weil man dieses n direkt hinter das "hab" hängt beim Aussprechen, kann man diese zwei Dinger auch gleich hintereinander schreiben:

> Ich hab'n' Führerschein.

Ende.

Comment: Die Leute, die einen Akkusativ kennen sagen aber nicht *Ich hab ein' Führerschein* sagen, sondern *Ich hab ein'n Führerschein*. Wer wirklich *Ich hab ein' Führerschein* sagt, der tut das nicht der Verkürzung wegen, sondern weil er zu faul ist, einen korrekten Akkusativ zu verwenden.